# using dropzone.js in webform with master page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages, dropzone.js

I'm trying to get the dropzonejs script to work in a asp.net site with master page and child webforms. I got a good idea how to from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050965/using-dropzone-js-in-asp-net) question but that works on a simple webform..how do I get it to work on an aspx page that has a master page?

So my masterpage right now has this:

```
<body class="fixed-top">
     <form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off" class="dropzone">
       <div id="container">
            <div id="body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </form>
</body>
```

and in my aspx page I have this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     <h3 class="page-title">Filemanager</h3>
     <div class="box"> <!--INSIDE THIS IS WHERE I WOULD WANT DROPZONE TO LOAD-->
        <div>
            <div class="fallback">
                <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

the problem is that it loads but outside the containers..any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to make it work in a Master/Child page scenario.

1. Since I am using a div element instead of the form element in the child page, I need to assign the url as an option. (see script block below)
2. Make sure give your form element the class="dropzone", it is missing in your code.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
           paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
           maxFilesize: 2, // MB
           url: "/user/tasks/photoupload.aspx?tid=<%=Request.QueryString["tid"]%>"
       };
   </script>

   <div id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone">
       <div class="fallback">
           <input name="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" runat="server"/>
           <input name="btnUpload" type="submit" /><br /><br />
           <asp:Label id="lblFallbackMessage" runat="server" />
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Good luck.

Comment: thanks! but does that photoupload.aspx a seperate page? or is it the same page?

Comment: It is the same page.  My codebehind looks very similar to the answer you referenced above.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050965/using-dropzone-js-in-asp-net)

Comment: Another option I thought of but didn't try was to add the dropzone functionality in an IFRAME.  Then I would have all my content from the master page but the dropzone code could live in a stand-alone aspx page all by itself. I think that would work.

Comment: I've tried dropzone in an iframe and it didn't look pretty lol but thanks i'll give this a try