# Dropzone.js: Upload images to server in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js to upload images to the browser. I need to upload these images to the server. Do I need to use Handler.ashx to get the images, and How can I do that? Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function (obj) {
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element
        // The configuration we've talked about above
        url: '#',
        previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        maxFiles: 100,
        dictDefaultMessage: "",
        accept: function(file, done) {
         //in here I can access each file that dropping on to the browser   

            },

        init: function () {
            this.on("drop", function (file) {

            });


            this.on("uploadprogress", function (file, progress) {
                //if (progress == 100) {
                console.log(progress);
                //}
            });
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                alert("No more files please!");
            });

            this.on("complete", function (file) {
                if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                    alert(file.name);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    createDropzone();});
```

I am new to this area, Any help?

Comment: No, I'am not using MVC

Answer (score 2):

I have done this with mvc.So I didn't need any handler to do this.
Uploading file done by using javascript.

Since you are using normal asp.net here is a post that you should refer.
You 'll not need any handlers.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16051735/3156647

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally I'm going to upload the images to the Azure Cloud Storage. After that user should be able to download the images (compressed in to a one zip file) directly by a link send to his/her email. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Here is a example of creating zip files using asp.net.
You can create a zip file of images and get the path of the generated zip file and send that to the users.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5089e0/how-to-create-zip-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp/