# Struggling with getting Dropzone to work with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, dropzone

I'm trying to get dropzone.js to work in asp.net in C# (not mvc) on a bootstrap site.  I've followed this tutorial but can't get it to work as nothing happens when I drag/drop the file.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050965/using-dropzone-js-in-asp-net

The super frustrating part is that when I try to run it locally to make sure I've got the correct path to upload, the breakpoints don't fire, so it's like my code behind isn't used at all once I've dropped the file.   How do I get the codebehind to fire when I drag/drop the file so I can trouble shoot?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DropZone.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- Datatables.net CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.3/b-1.5.6/b-colvis-1.5.6/b-flash-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/b-print-1.5.6/cr-1.5.0/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/kt-2.5.0/r-2.2.2/rg-1.1.0/rr-1.2.4/sc-2.0.0/sl-1.3.0/datatables.min.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <form id="demoupload" runat="server" class="dropzone needsclick" action="/upload">
           <div>
                <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="file" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa8bd4cc4b.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.3/b-1.5.6/b-colvis-1.5.6/b-flash-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/b-print-1.5.6/cr-1.5.0/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/kt-2.5.0/r-2.2.2/rg-1.1.0/rr-1.2.4/sc-2.0.0/sl-1.3.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <!--Local Link to js for DropZone  Needs to be After Bootstrap-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropzone.js"></script>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

and my code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string s in Request.Files)

        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];

            int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
            string fileName = Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
            string fileExtension = "";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(@"R:\Inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\test\", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension);

        file.SaveAs(savedFileName);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try removing the action attribute from the form. I don't think that should be there. That may stop the postback from working.

Comment: @user1751825  Thank you.  Removing the action attribute from the form helped, as I can now step thru the code.  I see that the filename is coming across as empty.  It's losing that somehow..

Comment: You should be able to just use file.filename, no need to use that header.

Comment: @user1751825  Thank you!  That change to file.filename did the trick.  I really appreciate the help with both issues.  Thank you!!